# How can I achieve an 'almost' full screen modal in React Native?

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I'm not sure what you call this type of modal, but one that is trendy on iOS that doesn't quite make it full screen, maybe it's 10% margin from the top. Here's an image:

Here's my *standard* Modal setup:

```
<Modal visible={imageViewerVisible} transparent={true} onRequestClose={() => this.setImageViewerVisible(false)} style={{ backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
      <ImageViewer imageUrls={ images } index={0} onSwipeDown={() => this.setImageViewerVisible(false) } enableSwipeDown={true} />
</Modal>
```

I'm not sure if there's a prop I can use or it might not be the native react-native modal? Not even sure what people are calling this type of modal! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just called presentationStyle!

Adding the prop presentationStyle="pageSheet" does the trick.

```
<Modal presentationStyle="pageSheet" visible={imageViewerVisible} transparent={true} onRequestClose={() => this.setImageViewerVisible(false)} style={{ backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
      <ImageViewer imageUrls={ images } index={0} onSwipeDown={() => this.setImageViewerVisible(false) } enableSwipeDown={true} />
</Modal>
```

Comment: `presentationStyle` is iOS-only. Is there something similar for Android?

Comment: WARN: Modal with 'pageSheet' presentation style and 'transparent' value is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

The **presentationStyle** prop controls how the modal appears (generally on larger devices such as iPad or plus-sized iPhones) so for Android we can use **statusBarTranslucent** which determines whether our modal should go under the system statusbar.

```
 <Modal
  statusBarTranslucent={true}
  animationType="fade"
  transparent={true}
```

Comment: WARN: Modal with 'pageSheet' presentation style and 'transparent' value is not supported.

Comment: statusBarTranslucent worked on android

Comment: statusBarTranslucent worked on react-native with expo, presentationStyle isn't working

Answer (score 0):

The modal is not covering the entire screen
The modal style applied by default has a small margin.
If you want the modal to cover the entire screen you can easily override it this way:

```
<Modal style={{ margin: 0 }}>...</Modal>
```